# Different behavior of Docker and Docker Compose when exposing X

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am trying to run X apps within a docker container and display the GUI.
I got this working with Docker Compose, but when running the same container from the command line with `docker run`, it fails.

I have created a minimal example to try to demonstrate what is happening:

Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y x11-apps
RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash xvis
USER xvis
WORKDIR /home/xvis
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3"
services:
  xeyes-test:
    build: .
    command: xeyes
    volumes:
      - /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix
    environment:
      DISPLAY: unix:0
```

`docker-compose up --build`  brings up the xeyes GUI, as expected.

`docker build -t xeyes-docker-test .`
`docker run --rm -e DISPLAY:unix:0 -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix xeyes-docker-test xeyes`

gives the error: `Error: Can't open display:`

Comment: I get the error (consistently) both ways. The `docker run` command should be `-e DISPLAY=unix:0` (not `:`). If that doesn't resolve it, see: https://github.com/jessfraz/dockerfiles/issues/329

Comment: Thanks @DazWilkin, that was the issue.  The syntax of the two systems is slightly different which threw me off.  
If you post your comment as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docker run command should be `-e DISPLAY=unix:0` (`=` not `:`).

If that doesn't resolve it, see: https://github.com/jessfraz/dockerfiles/issues/329